# Xamarin forms MainPage = new page(); is this makes dispose when we assign new page

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can anybody help me with this knowledge. My question is below.

**Xamarin forms MainPage = new page(); is this makes dispose when we assign new page**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: No, assigning a new value will not `Dispose` the old one. It _may_ make it eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: You can test this using [Finalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=net-5.0) method ,  this method is called before    it is reclaimed by garbage collection. just make a output in the previous page to see if it will be triggered after calling `MainPage = new page(); ` .

Comment: @mjwills,  Hi, I need to check like where i get the old one back if i assign new value. We are not handling the NavigationStack right.

Comment: It is difficult cause it is managed by garbage collection .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, Thanks for the update. Then the old one stays in garbage collection and it consumes memory. Dispose will clean up the memory right?

Comment: Yes ,but there is no API to dispose object manually with GC.